# jQuery selector not replacing text

Tags: jquery

I have a table and I am trying to replace text in what should be the sibling of the filename td but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
var current = $(".filename:contains('image.jpg')").siblings();
current.find(".filesize").text('new text');
```

The HTML:

```
<table id="uploadifive-fileupload-queue" class="table table-striped uploadifive-queue">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="uploadifive-queue-item complete" id="uploadifive-fileupload-file-0">
            <td class="preview">thumb</td>
            <td class="filename">image.jpg</td>
            <td class="filesize">100x100</td> 
            <td class="fileinfo">Failed</td>
            <td class="fileactions">Create Thumbnail</td>
            <td class="filedelete"><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you are searching for siblings children not the siblings themselves.  To search the siblings use a selector in the siblings function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In one line

```
$(".filename:contains('image.jpg')").siblings(".filesize").text('new text');
```

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot siblings can take a selector, I'll remove my answer as yours is better :)

Answer (score 4):

`current` is a set of all siblings.

```
current.find(".filesize")
```

This is looking for `.filesize` as a child of `current`.  You want `.filter` instead, to find an item in the set:

```
current.filter(".filesize").text('new text');
```

Answer (score 3):

find only searches through children. Not siblings.

if you change it to...

```
var current = $(".filename:contains('image.jpg')").parent();
current.find(".filesize").text('new text');
```

it works